# Depth cameras with varying illuminations

Tags: sensors, cameras

We realized that depth cameras (IFM) tend to create a lot of noise when exposed in areas with direct sunlight. Are there any approaches to deal with illuminations? Eliminating pixels for instance?

Answer (score 2):

depth cameras are super cool. I have never worked with them before, but guess what? I have an opinion! lol.

Have you considered using a lens to filter out the direct sunlight as a "cover" (kind of a baseball hat brim). I recall when there was an eclipse we looked at it through a welder's mask and it was super cool as you could see the actual eclipse! maybe putting a filter to prevent the sun hitting your sensor is the way to go; you could use the same principle to prevent the sun hitting your sensor.

With most chips, the light intensity of direct sun is going to give you such a high value on those pixels that it will blind your sensor, and you won't be able to do squat about that unless you use a light filter... but then you could end up filtering the light your camera senses..

I have no idea what your application is, but touch base with your sensor manufacturer and see what they can suggest for your issue. Another "in the dark" idea is using an IMU to know when you are facing upwards at the sun, and knowing your data is compromised.

As a closing thought, unless the light emitted by the camera is light that is outside the spectrum emitted by the sun, you cannot look at the sun and get a valid distance read (thats how "anti-cop" radar blinders work).

If the manufacturer has no help, I would focus on either:

1. figuring out when I am looking at the sun and looking away
2. Blocking the sun out using filters as a kind of roof over the sensor.

Good luck in your adventure.